# Get cell's data in excel file and save it to text file

Tags: excel, vb.net, text

I try to take cell's data from excel file and save this data on text file, but after I use this code:

```
 Imports System.IO 
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop 
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
Private myWriter As New StreamWriter("C:\myFile.txt")
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim XRng As Excel.Range
Dim CellValue As String

Private Sub btnRead_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click

    appXL = New Excel.Application
    wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Worksheet.xlsx")
    appXL.Visible = True
    appXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    shXL = wbXL.Worksheets(1)
    shXL.Visible = True
    XRng = CType(appXL.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet).Range("A1").Value2
    CellValue = XRng.ToString()
    myWriter.WriteLine(CellValue)
    myWriter.Close()
    wbXL.Close()
    appXL.Quit()
End Sub
End Class
```

The result in text file was  `System.__ComObject`

What should I make correction in the code?

Comment: I'm no windows programmer, but I would guess that the System.__ComObject *is* the cell object, but when you ToString it, it doesn't know what properties you want to take out, so it writes it like it would in an error or interactive session. Try getting the text value out of the cell instead of just ToStringing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CellValue = XRng.ToString()`, try using `CellValue = XRng.Value`.